# How to use Logging into Akka actor?

Tags: scala, akka

Can I set Logging in Akka actor by implicit? I would like to log inside the actor. My code is as given below:

```
object EmployeeRouterActor {
  final case class Employee(id: Long, name: String)
  final case object StopChild
  final case class ChildResponse(id: Long, name: String)
}

final class EmployeeRouterActor extends Actor with akka.actor.ActorLogging {

  import EmployeeRouterActor._

  private var children = Map.empty[Long, ActorRef]

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case e @ Employee(id, _)  => {
      getChild(id) ! e
    }
    case r @ ChildResponse(id, _) => {
      stopChild(id)
      val idItem = r.id
      val nameItem = r.name
      sender ! s"Employee {$idItem} is $nameItem."
    }
  }

  private def getChild(id: Long): ActorRef =
    context.child(id.toString).getOrElse {
      val child = context.actorOf(EmployeeEchoActor.apply(), id.toString)
      children += (id -> child)
      child
    }

  private def stopChild(id: Long) = {
    children(id) ! StopChild
    children -= id
  }

}
```

But, in this case, I can not do something like this:

```
class EmployeeRouterActor (implicit logger: LoggingAdapter) { ... }
```

I have got following errors:

```
Error:(10, 30) could not find implicit value for parameter logger: akka.event.LoggingAdapter
  def apply(): Props = Props(new EmployeeEchoActor)

Error:(10, 30) not enough arguments for constructor EmployeeEchoActor: (implicit logger: akka.event.LoggingAdapter)actors.EmployeeEchoActor.
Unspecified value parameter logger.
  def apply(): Props = Props(new EmployeeEchoActor)
```

Is it possible to use Logging from Akka inside the actors?

EmployeeEchoActor (child actor) is defined as given below:

```
object EmployeeEchoActor {
  def apply(): Props = Props(new EmployeeEchoActor)
}

class EmployeeEchoActor(implicit logger: LoggingAdapter) extends Actor {

  override def receive = {

    case employee: EmployeeRouterActor.Employee => {
      logger.info("Message received!")
      val idItem = employee.id
      val nameItem = employee.name
      context.parent ! EmployeeRouterActor.ChildResponse( idItem, nameItem )

    }
    case EmployeeRouterActor.StopChild => {
      logger.info("Stopping :(!")
      context.stop(self)
    }
    case _ => sender ! "Internal Error!"
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have an `implicit val LoggingAdapter` available in the place where you create the `EmployeeEchoActor` and pass it to the `Props` constructor?

Comment: I just updated post to show EmployeeEchoActor. I pass Logging, but I do not know how I have to refactor Porps constructor. This is my first time in Akka and I can not find any similar at Google or here.

Comment: Did you have a look at this page?
 http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/logging.html

Comment: No, I did not. I am going to have a look right now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
final class EmployeeRouterActor extends Actor with akka.actor.ActorLogging {
```

Implement ActorLogging and use log at code, for example:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case e @ Employee(id, _)  => {
      log.info("Message received!")
      getChild(id) ! e
    }
    case r @ ChildResponse(id, _) => {
      log.info("Response received from child!")
      stopChild(id)
      log.info("Child has been stopped!")
      val idItem = r.id
      val nameItem = r.name
      sender ! s"Employee {$idItem} is $nameItem."
    }

  }
```